Why is my pyrgeometer calibrated as if it has $a >1$ emissivity?
I've acquired an SL-510-SS upward-looking pyrgeometer.
In the manual it gives the formula for how to compute the downwelling infrared it picks up:

Clearly the $k_2$ coefficient is the emissivity of the sensor, according to which it emits infrared radiation proportional to the 4th power of its temperature.
Yet on my calibration certificate, $k_2$ is listed as 1.028 .
This implies $a >1$ emissivity, and leads to impossible results. For example, placing it in a cavity it will report as if the walls are emitting with emissivity >1.0 at equilibrium, which is physically impossible as I understand it.
What is going on here?
